# CostPath gives error for specific points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, cost-path

I am using the tool CostPath. As an input feature destination data I've entered several points (no specific value, just distributed geographically), and as the cost distance raster I've entered the cost distance raster previously done with CostDistance.

My question is that I can draw the CostPath line from all the points except for three and I cannot figure out why.

- I've been able to draw to CostPath lines from all the points with other CostDistance rasters, however it is not possible to draw the CostPath line for this specific CostDistance raster and for the same three points.
- I've run CostPath with those signle three points, but still nothing happens to them. On the contrary, I used the same points with previous CostDistance rasters and worked.
- I've checked in my CostDistance raster/Layer Properties/Source/NoData Value, and is empty. As the other CostDistance rasters that didn't give problems.
- I've checked the BackLink produced in CostDistance and has a NoData Value of 255. Does anybody think that NoData values may be the problem? If not, which it is?

Could you be so kind as to figure out the possible problem and solution?

(I've re-drawn that particular CostDistance raster several times and nothing happens, that's why I need your help to figure out which problem there could be).

Comment: Does Cost Distance give an error (if so, what), or just ignore some of the destination points? What happens if you use only those three points as destinations and leave out the ones that work?

Comment: Thanks Erica! 1) Cost Distance does not give any error, neither Cost Path; 2) Cost Path just ignore does destination points (that btw I draw them at the same time in the same layer); 3) I'have also run CostPath with those signle three points, but still nothing happens to them. On the contrary, I used the same points with other CostDistance rasters and worked then. I may guess that there could be a problem with the current CostDistance raster en NoData?

Comment: My guess then is that NoData is getting in the way -- CostPath treats those as "impossible to cross" rather than "zero cost", so if destination points are surrounded by NoData you can't get to them.

Comment: Thanks! I have checked in my CostDistance raster/Layer Properties/Source/NoData Value, and is empty. As the other CostDistance rasters that didn't give problems. My question is: Is this the correct way to check if there are NoData values in the raster. If not, which it is? If NoData Values are no the problem, then which could be?

Comment: I have observed that the associated Back Link produced in CostDistance has a NoData Value of 255. However the other Back Links produced in the other CostDistance rasters also have NoData Value of 255.... so I may think is another issue.

Comment: Rather than create a trail of comments, which potential answerers may not have the inclination to read through, I recommend that you incorporate responses to any requests for clarification by editing your original question to a revised state.